# Using custom field in freemember registration form

Tags: freemember

I have a Select custom member field, how do I display this in the Freemember registration form?

it is called "school", the below code does not seem to work, maybe I am doing it wrong?

{field:school}

EE 2.7

```
                    {exp:freemember:register return="{segment_1}/{segment_2}/register-success" error_handling="inline" error_delimiters='<span class="error">|</span>'}

                    <p class="form-element">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" value="" class="txtbox" /><br />
                        {error:username}
                    </p>

                    <p class="form-element">
                        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" value="" class="txtbox" /><br />
                        {error:email}
                    </p>

                    <p class="form-element">
                        <label for="school">School</label>
                        {field:school}
                        {error:school}
                    </p>

                    <p class="form-element">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="txtbox" /><br />
                        {error:password}
                    </p>

                    <p class="form-element">
                        <label for="password_confirm">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password_confirm" value="" class="txtbox" /><br />
                        {error:password_confirm}
                    </p>

                    {if captcha}
                    <p class="form-element">
                        <label for="captcha" style="margin-bottom:5px;">Please enter the following characters into the box below:</label>
                        <br />{captcha}<br />
                        <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" class="txtbox" /><br />
                        {error:captcha}
                    </p>
                    {/if}   

                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </p>

                {/exp:freemember:register}
```

Comment: From memory that should work. What does it output? Does it display anything at all?

Comment: It displays the tag as plain text only

Comment: Really stuck on this, not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Just did some testing and custom member fields are working fine for me. Are you running the latest version of Freemember? Are you sure your custom field names are correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me, so here are some things to check:

- Make sure you running the latest version of FreeMember
- Make sure you spelled the custom field correctly. Do you have a prefix that you use for the custom member fields or anything?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work unfortunately.

I ended up using a custom member field name in a select drop down populated by categories, so the client could update and change the list options.
Thanks